# SSRS conditional formatting (Using AND and OR)

Tags: algorithm, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, conditional-formatting, iif

I have a question regarding a complicated conditional formatting that I currently trying to put in place. The code is:

```
=iif(Fields!ACT.Value = "N/V", "No Color",
iif(Fields!ACT.Value = "N/K", "No Color",
iif(Fields!ACT.Value = "N/A", "No Color",
iif(Fields!NUM.Value < Fields!SHORT.Value , "Yellow", 
iif(Fields!NUM.Value > Fields!INC.Value, "Orange", 
iif((isnothing(Fields!ACT.Value <> "N/A" and Fields!NUM.Value) or isnothing(Fields!ACT.Value <> "N/K" and Fields!NUM.value) or isnothing(Fields!ACT.Value <> "N/V" and Fields!NUM.Value)), "Purple", "No Color"))))))
```

It all works fine up until the last IIF where it references isnothing. I've tried lots of different things to solve it and what is happening is that either it doesn't apply the purple to any cells which are blank, or it applies the purple colour to all blank cells even if they are N/A, N/K or N/V. 
Could anyone shed some light on why this is occurring? I've tried just dealing with that one line of code and ignoring the rest but to no success.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is:

```
isnothing(Fields!ACT.Value <> "N/A" and Fields!NUM.Value) or isnothing(Fields!ACT.Value <> "N/K" and Fields!NUM.value) or isnothing(Fields!ACT.Value <> "N/V" and Fields!NUM.Value)
```

always return `True` because of inner boolean expressions are always not null.

Second: Instead of combination of `iif` you can use `switch`.

So, I think, you should try this expression:

```
=Switch
(
    Fields!ACT.Value = "N/V", "No Color",
    Fields!ACT.Value = "N/K", "No Color",
    Fields!ACT.Value = "N/A", "No Color",
    Fields!NUM.Value < Fields!SHORT.Value, "Yellow", 
    Fields!NUM.Value > Fields!INC.Value, "Orange", 
    IsNothing(Fields!NUM.Value), "Purple",
    True, "No Color"
)
```

**EDIT:**

I changed expression code according your last comment.

Don't forget, that order of conditions in `switch` is **important**! `The Switch function returns the value associated with the first expression in a series that evaluates to true` (c)MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328(v=sql.105).aspx)

So you should `IsNothing` expression in last order, only before default value.

Comment: Hi I've tried this version and it is still making the NULL values for N/A, N/K and N/V purple. I'm trying to make all columns that are NULL purple except for the N/A, N/K and N/V when they should be No Color based on the rules given to me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for updating but I'm still having an issue with the IN. For some reason it still underlines it in SSRS and when I hover over it the message is syntax error. When I split them out, so ACT is equal to N/A etc. It still flags the NULL fields for those N/A etc. as Purple rather than leaving them as No Color. I think this is because the IsNothing is overriding the the No Color at the top for N/A.

Comment: I amended my code to have the IsNothing more explicit `(left(Fields!ACTIVITY_MONTH_NAME.Value, 2) <> "N/" and isnothing(Fields!NUMBER_OF_RECORDS.Value)), "Purple", True, "No Color"` however it is still colouring is still going purple for NULL N/A, N/K and N/V. I don't know how to make the grouping stop applying the formatting for just those three values.

Comment: I don't see any mistakes in your code... Maybe the problem in `Fields!ACTIVITY_MONTH_NAME.Value`? Maybee there are some trailing spaces or something else. Try to use this: `(left(Fields!ACTIVITY_MONTH_NAME.Value.ToString().Trim(), 2) <> "N/" and isnothing(Fields!NUMBER_OF_RECORDS.Value)), "Purple", True, "No Color"`

Comment: Thanks very much. That is now working. Seems that are some spaces in there. Thanks very much for your help and time with this.

Comment: Hooray! =) I'm realy-realy happy for you! =)

Answer (score 1):

Your last `Iif` statement with `IsNothing` function is not written in right context, because condition in `IsNothing` function always return `true`.

Also, rewrite your OR conditions with NOT IN clause to shrink your code and make more readable.

```
=Switch
(
    Fields!ACT.Value IN ("N/V", "N/K", "N/A"), "No Color",
    Fields!NUM.Value < Fields!SHORT.Value, "Yellow", 
    Fields!NUM.Value > Fields!INC.Value, "Orange", 
    IsNothing(Fields!NUM.Value) and (Fields!ACT.Value NOT IN ("N/A", "N/K", "N/V"), "Purple",
    True, "No Color"
)
```

Think of your expression to avoid overlapping each other.

Comment: Hi. I've tried this and unfortunately it throws an error with the IN statement. It underlines it as syntax error and expects a Comma or ).